# Solution of Lyapunov matrix equation by matrix exponential function

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Consider the following Lyapunov matrix equation:

$A^T X + XA = -I$,

where superscript $T$ denotes transpose, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

I am aware that if $A$ is Hurwitz stable, then $X$ is unique and positive definite. It also holds that

$X=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{A^Tt}e^{At} dt$.

Also, $X$ must be symmetric.

The problem with the last equation is that it is extremely computationally costly. I tried coding it in MATLAB and Python, but even for $n=3$ its computation takes forever! (For $n=2$ it is good and correct).

I have read some papers on numerical solution of the Lyapunov matrix equation. My question: Is the mentioned formula useless and impractical?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean something like [the lyap function in Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lyap.html)? Or are you looking for functions that can give symbolic/exact solutions?

Comment: The second expression for $X$ is incorrect. Other than that, those expressions are only used in theoretical works. There are better computational tools for calculating the solution to the Lyapunov equation.

Comment: @KBS, You're right. I removed the incorrect  equation. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Mathisfreedom If you're using Python, you can just use the scipy [solve_continuous_lyapunov](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_continuous_lyapunov.html) method or the [solve_sylvester](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_sylvester.html) method. Under the hood, both of these use the [Bartels-Stewart algortihm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartels%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm) for Sylvester equations.

Comment: @Mathisfreedom As KBS has mentioned, the integral is more useful for understanding the theoretical properties of the solution. For instance, the integral formula makes it easier to understand how the solution varies as $A$ changes.